# How to loop through a few of my column names (like document1 through document5) and set their value to a file on my filesystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have any number of document attachments output to a folder by another script and a certain file type is prepended to the filename when they are output there. The various file types could have two to 4 documents each.

I'm looping through all files in that folder and based on the doctype prepended to it, I want to use paperclip to attach them to several paperclip fields I set up for each corresponding file type. An assumption here is that there are no more than four files for each doc type so the model has four fields for each document type. So in the case of all files with file type "document", i want to put each of them in the available paperclip fields in the model called document1, document2, document3 or document4

Here's an example of my code assuming that 'document' is prepended to the file name and that i need to put them in document1, document2, document3 or document4:

```
document_number = 1

Dir['output/*'].each do |item|

    filename_array = item.split(" ")

    open(item) do |f|
      case filename_array.first.gsub("output/", "")

        when "document"
          lap.attributes["document#{document_number.to_s}"] = f
          lap.save!
          document_number = document_number + 1
        when "zip"
        ... more document types

      end


    end

    FileUtils.rm(item)
end
```

The output in the terminal shows the following in the spot that it should be handling the file with paperclip:

```
(0.4ms)  COMMIT
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
```

*edited to make it clearer what the problem is and updating code with suggestions from comments

Comment: what does `lap` do?? And why are you opening the file twice, one closes the file the other does not, I can memory leakage somewhere, then you are deleting the file when it has not being closed

Comment: are the column names fixed or do you want a method that handels column names flexible?

Comment: lap is just a model that has a few attachments in it's list of columns

Comment: The column names are fixed. This is a bad hack it seems to being able to allow up to five documents to be attached. @bjhaid I'll remove the second file open. didnt realize that thanks

Comment: @TaimoorQ if lap is a model you want to do something like `lap.name = "document#{document_number.to_s}"; lap.blob = f; lap.save!` Then you should remove the `File.open(item)` then move `FileUtils.rm(item)` into the outermost loop

Comment: I tried to change the first part of the where clause to be `lap.name = "document#{document_number.to_s}";` but now get the following error `undefined method `name=' for #<Lap:0x0000010b94a410>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to pass the dynamic column names in as a hash with the file so the final code ended up looking like this:

```
document_number = 1

Dir['output/*'].each do |item|

  filename_array = item.split(" ")

  open(item) do |f|
    case filename_array.first.gsub("output/", "")

      when "document"
        lap.attributes = { "document#{document_number.to_s}" => f }
        lap.save!
        document_number = document_number + 1
      when "zip"
      # ... more document types

    end


  end

  FileUtils.rm(item)
end
```

Then once the model saves paperclip knows what to do to get it's columns updated of course

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use paperclip interpolations, to specify where the file is saved.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations

```
:path => '/:column2/:column1/:column4_document:id.:extension'
```

You can extend Paperclip.interpolates to do whatever you want.

```
Paperclip.interpolates :my_file_name_path do |attachment, style|
  stuff...
end
```

Then use it like

```
:path => '/:my_file_name_path'
```

Comment: thanks but i'm fine with where it puts them, the problem is another script from a different application is extracting these documents into a folder with a naming convention for what type of attachment in the lap model it should go in